# BASIC認証が掛かっているDockerコンテナレジストリにhyper/docker-registry-webを繋ぎたい

Tags: docker

Dockerコンテナレジストリをプライベートに立てるために、[registryコンテナ](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/)を利用してレジストリを立てています。
またこのコンテナは外に疎通するように前段にLet's encryptによるTLS化をした上でBASIC認証を仕掛けて、dockerからは認証した上で利用出来ることを確認してあります。

このコンテナレジストリに対して、内容物をブラウザ上から確認できるようにしたいなと思いました。そこで調べるとよく使われる手段として[hyper/docker-registry-web](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyper/docker-registry-web/)コンテナが見つかりました。

このコンテナを使って対象のレジストリに対するチェックを行いたいのです。
しかし、BASIC認証を仕掛けている時、実際にはREADMEに乗っているように

```
REGISTRY_URL: レジストリのURL
REGISTRY_NAME: レジストリ名
REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH: BASE64エンコードしたBASIC認証の id:password ペア
```

というような設定を、環境変数に入れたのですが、実際にはブラウザを開くと

```
status=401 UNAUTHORIZED <html> <head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head> <body> <center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx</center> </body> </html>
```

というエラーが表示されます。
このエラーログを読む限りBASIC認証に失敗して動作していないように思えます。

そこで質問です。
このREGISTRY_BASIC_AUTHはつなぐ先のレジストリにかかったBASIC認証値を設定するものではないのでしょうか……？
またうまくこのような構成を行っている時に通信させる設定を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 同じ現象がIssueにも上がってますね https://github.com/mkuchin/docker-registry-web/issues/97

Comment: 最終commitが２年前でもうメンテされてなさ気＆「このプロジェクトは開発ストップなのか？」とIssueにあげている人がいるくらいなので、他のdocker registry UIを探したほうが良いかもです…　少し調べたところhttps://github.com/SUSE/Portus は日本語の情報があったのと、star数も2000超だったのでよいかもですね:+1:

Comment: おおー。ありがとうございます。なるほど単に古いんですね。あ、ただし、よかったらSOのシステム的に"質問に回答する"で答える形にしてもらえませんか。後で読む人に役立ちます。

Comment: 了解しました！同じ内容そのまま回答に書いておきますね.

Comment: ありがとうございます。お願いいたします〜。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 最終commitが２年前でもうメンテされてなさ気
- [このプロジェクトは開発ストップなのか？](https://github.com/mkuchin/docker-registry-web/issues/96)というIssueがあり、回答なし

ということがありますので、他のdocker registry UIを探したほうが良いかもです…

少し調べたところ[Portus](https://github.com/SUSE/Portus)は日本語の情報があったのと、star数も2000超だったのでよいかもですね。